# Запуск mainline kernel на android смартфоне

Tags: android, linux, kernel, железо, port

Xiaomi Mi MIX 2S, Snapdragon 845 (sdn845). Интересует запуск на минимальных параметрах конфигурации, только платформа и дисплей. Возможно ли не причинив вред проделать данный эксперимент? Если да, пожалуйста, ткните пальцем на ресурс для изучения

Comment: Легко не отделаться, скорее всего придёться разблокировать загрузчик и шить TWRP

Comment: Дисплей?! Это как раз часть, которую вы скорее всего не осилите сами. И что подразумевается под платформой?